# PFImageView loadInBackground() issue in iOS10

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfimageview

I am trying to use `PFImageView.loadInBackground()` in iOS10 .
So far my code has worked in iOS9 etc.

This is what I am doing:

- fetching image data
- assigning data to PFImageView.file
- loading file via PFImageView.file.loadInBackground()

The ImageData is found, but the image won't display.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with PFImageView when the file name for PFFile had white spaces.

Did you try running in Simulator what errors did you receive?

Comment: Seems like it is something with my tableView. can't even get an Image with UIImageView